# text symbol inserted to the div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am novice to the website coding. I have created a div area like textarea for typing words inside it. But now, I am coping with a problem. How do I paste a text symbol to the div area when I click or any other actions on the text symbol outside the div area ? Futhermore, Is it possible for me to convert the symbol into some kind of character when I send the content including text symbol(s) to my server ? pls give helps!

Comment: 86 the "pls give helps!" and copy paste it in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: We can only help when you've provided details we can work with. Can you show the code you've written instead of details about it?

Comment: @13ruce1337 actually StackOverflow now has runnable snippets! No longer is jsfiddle needed!

Comment: @SterlingArcher :O http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ AMAZING!! I literally shed a tear. TY Almight SO DEVS!

Comment: <div name="content" class="text" id="content" contenteditable="true"></div><table><tr><td>♛</td></tr></table>, they are the div area for comment and the table for holding text symbol(s). The situation is when I click '♛' , how do I paste it to the div area and ,further, send the comment including '♛' to server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to add symbols from the table to the div when a particular symbol is clicked, you can try this:

```
$('td').click({
    $('#content').append($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: it gets work. how about send the symbol with texts to server ,should I just send the whole comment including symbol  '♛' directly to the server? any ideas?

Comment: How are you communicating with the server? Via XMLHttpRequest? http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: I just try to connect server by php